# How to cite a combination

Tags: citations

I expected this simple, but cannot find any good source. Assume there are two sources, source A and source B. Both are different from each other, that is A provides some info on a problem, B provides other info. I would like to cite the combination. Something like: I do ... because ... (And, 2008; Byl, 2012). I realize I could split it somehow, but just assume that this combination makes sense in my context. Is the above way correct? I thought the ";" can only be used if both sources say the same thing. But here they are different parts, adding up together.

Thanks for any hints how to handle this correctly.

Comment: Please clarify the question. It sounds a little confusing.

Comment: @AcidKritana What I meant is if I need to prove a point based on two sources, lets say two books, I need to cite both of them in combination right? How is this done usually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Ankit below, you should do it that way. I cam across a statistic that came from multiple people. The author cited them like this: (I'm not going to use actual names, just random ones as an example)

> [Statistic.] (Jones and Capping)

Jones and Capping would both be last names. If you can, also indicate where the citation is, as in the number. Example:

> [Statistic.] (Jones and Capping)^1

Or

> [Statistic.] (Jones and Capping)[1]

The number would indicate which citation to look at, which is generally provided at the end. If this is a book, you could either do it at the end of each chapter or at the end of the book. Example of citations:

> [1] (APA citation)
>
> [2] (APA citation)
>
> [3] (APA citation)

The [1] or ^1 would indicate that the citation to look at is [1].

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what style (MLA/APA/Chicago) you are using but this is how my school teaches it:

(*intext citation 1* and *intext citation 2*)

Comment: thank you. Could you elaborate maybe how to do it in MLA and APA? I mean showing both would be nice to see the differences